# PHP date conversion to strtotime

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have an `array` where each record has a `'date'` field. The dates are in this format: `'10/09/2015'`. When I use `strtotime` on these dates, some of them come out as `false`. I thought there was a mistake in data structure so I created this simple `array` and a simple `foreach` loop, and they output `false` in some cases. What does it not like?

```
$dates = [];

$someData = [
    '21/05/2014',
    '22/05/2014',
    '09/06/2014',
    '04/07/2014',
];

foreach($someData as $date) {
    $dates[] = strtotime($date);
}

print_r($dates);die;
```

Comment: Look at `DateTime::createFromFormat` http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: What about `str_replace('/','-',$str);` @splash58. Seen after long time

Comment: @Uchiha Yes, it is OK!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand over here the date format of your date.
Here `m/d/Y` is considered to be the standard American Date format.

So when your date is like

```
'09/06/2014',//it should be considered as 06 september 2014
'04/07/2014',//it should be considered as 07 april 2014
```

And when your date is like as

```
'21/05/2014',
'22/05/2014',
```

Then the above date doesn't fits within the standards of American Date Format i.e. `m/d/Y` instead what you can do over here is replace `/` along with `-` which converts your date into European Date Format which is `d-m-Y`

Comment: Oh I see. That makes sense! Thank you. So the month comes first.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware of dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats; if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed. If the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. To avoid potential errors, you should YYYY-MM-DD dates or date_create_from_format() when possible.