# PHP strtotime outputs 1970

Tags: php

I have a string in an array which is like so

```
19/08/2015 12:08
```

I access this string using

```
$row["CREATE_DATE"]
```

If I do the following

```
var_dump($row["CREATE_DATE"] . "<br>");
var_dump(date("Ymd", strtotime($row["CREATE_DATE"])));
```

I get the output

```
string(20) "19/08/2015 12:08"
string(8) "19700101"
```

Why does the strtotime do my date as 1970?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP date conversion to strtotime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499055/php-date-conversion-to-strtotime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it in wrong way.Use this :

```
var_dump(date("Ymd", strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$row["CREATE_DATE"]))));
```

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) link for all the supported date formats

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$row["CREATE_DATE"]="19/08/2015 12:08";
echo $d=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row["CREATE_DATE"])); => 1970-01-01

But, When changing the format $row["CREATE_DATE"]="19-08-2015 12:08";
echo $d=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row["CREATE_DATE"])); => 2015-08-19

So, What @RaveenaNigam Said, We Have To Use This Way.
var_dump(date("Ymd", strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$row["CREATE_DATE"]))));
=> 2015-08-19
?>
```