# Difference in UK Dates

Tags: php, date, time

I am trying to show the difference in days and months between 2 dates

```
$date1 = $start;
$date2 = $end;
$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```

However this shows as `0 years, 0 months, 0 days`

The dates in `$start` and `$end` are in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`

Comment: @Prafulla who is this comment for?

Comment: Your input have the wrong format. You should use an other format or `DateTime::createFromFormat`.
Using the DateTime object makes your code also easier and you could just use `DateTime::diff()`

    $d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $date1);
    $d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $date2);
    
    $span = $d1->diff($d2);
    printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $span->y, $span->m, $span->d);

Comment: @shaun, actually i comment for derenir, who deleted his comment

Comment: convert date format `$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date11)->format('Y-m-d');
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date12)->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted? It isnt a duplicate due to the UK time format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated within your comment that *The dates in `$start` and `$end` are in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`*. So you need to first replace that into `d-m-Y` using `str_replace` or `DateTime::createFromFormat` so try using like as

```
$date1 = str_replace('/','-',$start);
$date2 = str_replace('/','-',$end);
```

[PHP date conversion to strtotime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499055/php-date-conversion-to-strtotime/32499148#32499148)

Comment: Thanks however still showing as `0. 0, 0`

Comment: Ignore me... working perfectly, Thank you!

Comment: I will do as soon as it lets me (in 5 mins)

Comment: You're Welcome. Glad it helped you.

Comment: Could I quickly ask... how do I remove days? so it just shows years and months?

Comment: `printf("%d years, %d months \n", $years, $months);`