# Date function in PHP Not working properly

Tags: php, date

While converting date format from  mm-dd-yy hh:ii:ss to yy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss format using below code.

```
<?php
echo $start_date =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("10-14-2015 00:00:00"));
?>
```

But the result is

1970-01-01 05:30:00

If it is not a proper way to use date ,provide me alternate way

Comment: `d-m-y` -> `10-14-2015` Where I life we don't have 14 months. (See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2167916/3933332)

Comment: 10-14-2015 00:00:00 is in mm-dd-yy format

Comment: mm-dd-yy is not in the list of supported strtotime formats: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499055/php-date-conversion-to-strtotime/32499148#32499148) answer whats the difference between dates over here and simply use `str_replace` like as

```
echo $start_date =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(str_replace("-","/","10-14-2015 00:00:00")));
```

Or you can also use `DateTime::createFromFormat` over like as

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y H:i:s","10-14-2015 00:00:00");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/444304)

Comment: Thanks ! for your answer.

Comment: You're Welcome. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
and also specify your PHP version.

It has a nice example on checking if strtotime conversion was successfull:

```
if (($timestamp = strtotime($str)) === false) {
```

And this conversion is very critical, it supports only limited number of formats that should be specified very precisely in order days/months/years, and separators / or - or :

So you have to pick the format that you will support from following list:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Be sure to create culturally aware code (e.g. US/UK/... format)

Answer (score 1):

Please write your code as below:
 `echo $start_date =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("10/14/2015 00:00:00"));`