# Unable to convert date in valid format PHP

Tags: php, jquery, date

I'm creating an application in which user enter a date and make a request. At server side I verify whether user has entered valid date or not . But what the problem comes is PHP isn't converting some of date user enters. For e.g
if user selects `13/10/15` with jquery datetimpicker and I print it,

```
print_r(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->request->post['delivery_date'])));
```

And its showing

```
1970-01-01
```

So I tried to check if any error is there or not. To do so I tried

```
$date = date_parse($this->request->post['delivery_date']);
print_r($date);
```

And it's showing an error

```
[error_count] => 1
[errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Unexpected character
        )
```

It works fine for other dates but not with some dates. What should I do? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how are you requesting the date

Comment: User selects a date and click button. Then using ajax i check it for validation.

Comment: are you getting requested date properly??

Comment: @ved pandya are you sending the date via ajax call .which type of method are you using and print your delivery date in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date conversion to strtotime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499055/php-date-conversion-to-strtotime)

Comment: @Uchiha yes ! How did you know it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward slash (/) signifies American `M/D/Y` formatting, and there isn't a thirteenth month in our calendar.

```
print_r(date('Y-m-d',strtotime("10/13/15")));
```

Should be good. Or use `DateTime::createFromFormat` like

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', '13/10/15');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2015-10-13
```

Comment: yes that's right but i don't want to change date format of my date-picker. So isn't there any solution?

Comment: For `13/11/15` it prints `1970-01-01` but for `03/11/15` it prints `2015-03-11`. :|

Comment: +1 For DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', '13/10/15'); :) Thanks. It works. But why strtotime not works same ?

Comment: Because forward slash (/) signifies American `M/D/Y` in `strtotime`, like I wrote above

Answer (score 0):

```
   $str = '24/12/2013';
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $str);
   echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```